# How do I deal with duplicate lemmas in Spacy

Tags: parsing, spacy, lemmatization

I'm parsing the following two sentences using the `en_core_web_sm` model version 2.0.0: `"Rabbits are mammals"` and `"Rabbits have hair"`. In the first sentence I'm getting a token with lemma `'rabbit'`, id `10130653840019909946` while in the second I'm getting `'rabbits'` with id `4224103442939446549`. This is surprising. Is it a bug in the model or am I misunderstanding something? I've tried doing the same with `en_core_web_md`, but got exactly the same results.

Comment: How do you see token id?

Comment: @arman, I'm referring to the lemma property of the token object.